# Manifest merger failed after adding Gurux in dependence

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to add [Gurux](https://github.com/Gurux/gurux.serial.android) to my android project by adding `implementation 'org.gurux:gurux.serial.android:1.0.1'` to my build.gradle-file, but I got an error saying "Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details."

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source manifest](https://github.com/Gurux/gurux.serial.android/blob/master/gurux.serial.java.android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) there are two activity components that do not have explicit `android:exported` value that is required when targeting Android 12 or above.

You can override the manifest entries in your own application-level manifest and provide the missing attributes, e.g.

```
<application>
    <activity
        android:name="USBAccessoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="gurux.serial.GXProperties"
        android:exported="true"/>
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working now!